# mongodb to link back images stored in directory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to store image in seperate directory and link it back to database, but i am quite lost because I have subarrays which stores images. here is my code to explain it better.

request.js // Model

```
  whoCreated: String,
  specialRequest: String,
  contactInformation: {
    name: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    requestDate: String,
  },
  installations: [{
    ref: 'phase',
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,

  }],
```

this installations has it own template and where images are basically stored..

Installations.js // Model

```
phase: {
    text: String,
    textKey: String,
    index: String,
    subjects: [{
      id: String,
      text: String,
      textKey: String,
      index: String,
      comment: String,
      image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }, // which currently stores base64Image
      imageName: String,
      answer: String,
```

}]

// route.js

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
    router.post('/request/partial', upload.single('checklistImage'), async (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.body.installations.subjects.base64Image);
      const request= new Request({
        whoCreated: req.body.whoCreated,
        specialRequest: req.body.specialRequest,
        contactInformation: req.body.contactInformation,
      });
      try {
        const install = req.body.installations;
        for (let i of install) {
          const savedPhases = await InstallationRequest.insertMany(i);
          for (let save of savedPhases) {
            await partial.installations.push(save._id);
          }
        }
        const saved = await request.save();
        return res.status(201).json({
          message: saved
        });
      } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
      }
    });
```

How do I link back the images in this route I am not sure how to link req.file.path ?

Comment: I would never store image or related binary data in database unless its absolutely necessary. I would store the image in my device and store the path of the image in database.

Comment: thats what I am trying to do, but I am not sure how do i implement it